# What is the difference between sheet and spreadsheet?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

As an English learner, I sometimes got confused the difference between spreadsheet and sheet.

Though I know what they mean, it seems that they both are referring to data in a table.

If I Google these words, most of the results are about how to use the software or features of the software.

However, I would really like to know what is the difference and why the word "spread" is used in the word.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Sheet* has several meanings: bedlinen, a flat area of something, a sheet of paper. The term *spreadsheet* has been coined for a particular computer application for manipulating data as though on a printed page, and that is what we would normally call such software. *Google Sheets* seems to be their own name for their own particular version of spreadsheets.

Comment: The word ["spreadsheet"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet#Paper_spreadsheets) predates computer software. It was originally a term for a bookkeeping table that was so large that it **spread** across two pages of an account book or was printed on double-size paper. This term was adopted by software companies to imply that the software is useful for keeping track of large tables of data.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thanks very much, this is the answer I'm looking for.